# How to insert repeated data to BigQuery table using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables with the following schemas:

1. **CLIENTS** with `(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_NAME)`
2. **ADDRESSES** with `(ADDRESS_ID, CLIENT_ID, STREET, ZIP_CODE)`

Assuming 1 address belongs to 1 client and 1 client may have several addresses.

I want to create one `D_CLIENTS` table in BigQuery with `CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_NAME, ADDRESSES` (record, repeated). How do I insert data to that table using SQL's `Insert into` script?

Answer (score 1):

I'll write the query that created the table (otherwise I can not insert), but modifying it to then insert should be trivial:

```
CREATE TABLE `deleting.addresses`
AS

WITH clients AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Dean Finn' AS name
), addresses AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([(STRUCT(8 AS id, 1 AS client_id, "Spear" AS street, "94105" AS zip))])
)

SELECT a.id client_id, ANY_VALUE(name) name, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(street, zip)) addresses
FROM clients a JOIN addresses b ON a.id=b.client_id
GROUP BY 1
```